# FFmpeg — calculate zoompan filter duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make 30 seconds video with smooth small zooming effect of an image. What i do:

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i 1.png -vf "zoompan=z='min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.0015,1.1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s='1000x1000'" -c:v libx264 -t 30 1.mp4`

How to modify my ffmpeg zoompan params for zoom effect during 30 seconds (all video time)? Now it produce 3 seconds effect at all. Docs says:

`d — Set the duration expression in number of frames. This sets for how many number of frames effect will last for single input image.`

But my experiments with `d` falied. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `d` only sets filter operation duration for each frame of your input. The duration for the zoom will be determined by the zoom expression.

zoom initializes with value `1`. So `'min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.0015,1.1)'` will clamp to value `1.1` after `(1.1 - 1) / 0.0015` frames, which is 66 frames. For a 25 fps input (default for inputs with no inherently recorded rate or timing), that's 2.64 seconds.

To keep zooming for 30 seconds, either decrease `0.0015` or increase `1.1`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you saved my time!

Comment: @Gyan Still can't understand this d in command. Can you explain more?